# Issue giving up focus on control

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am running into an odd issue using Blazor Webassembly. I have a component that has 2 text boxes. For some reason, if I type anything into the first text box, then try to either tab to the second text box or click in the second text box, I have to do it twice. It's like the first tab or click doesn't register. After playing around with it, I was able to minimally duplicate the issue. The issue seems to happen when I have both a model binding on the control and I use a `@ref` attribute.

Here is my `.cshtml` file:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@page "/"


<div>
    <input class="form-control" id="first-text-box" type="text" @ref="TextBoxControl" @bind="_model.Box1" />
</div>
<div>
    <input class="form-control" id="second-text-box" type="text" @bind="_model.Box2" />
</div>


@code {
    private ElementReference TextBoxControl { get; set; }
    private readonly BoxClass _model = new BoxClass();

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("jsFunctions.focusElement", TextBoxControl);

        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}
```

Here is the `focusElement` javascript function:

```
window.jsFunctions = {
    focusElement: function(element) {
        element.focus();
    }
};
```

Finally, here is a Fiddle of the issue to see it happen live: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/kph6msiv

Like I said, just type something into the first text box, then try to tab or click to the next text box and you'll see that you'll need to do it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are focusing every time it renders, which happens when Blazor data binds, which happens when you exit the control.

Instead, only call your JavsScript if `firstRender` is `true`

Comment: Don't forget to click the tick :)